# Get active network connections on OS X

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

Is there any way to retrieve active/inactive network connections without using shell scripts? CWInterface gives information only about WiFi networks and CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo is not available on OS X.

Comment: If you want the same information that you get by running ifconfig on the command line, you could do worse than reading the source code for it: https://opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-77/ifconfig.tproj/ifconfig.c

Answer (score 2):

```
        CWInterface* wifi = [[CWWiFiClient sharedWiFiClient] interface];
        int secType     = (int)[wifi security];
        int channel     = (int) [[wifi wlanChannel] channelNumber];
        int rssi        = [wifi rssiValue];
        NSString *ssid  = [wifi ssid];
        NSString *bssid = [wifi bssid];
```

Comment: You are welcome ;) I added `CWWiFiClient` after asking this question https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/pull/853

Comment: And `CWWiFiClient` is only available in OS X 10.10+.

Comment: Isn't this API for WLAN interfaces only? What about Ethernet interfaces?